# Can I use data in configuration profile in iPhone Simulator?

Tags: iphone, ios, configuration, ios-simulator

I want to know if I can use datas inside configuration profile generate by "Configuration Profile Utility". I want to return some informations for my application.

And i want to know if I can install a profile in iPhone Simulator or if I must do it on my device ?

Thank for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only install profiles on real device.